# Stylex fails to compile during jest tests: "stylex.create should never be called. It should be compiled away."

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, babeljs, stylexjs

Stylex compiles fine when I'm developing normally with webpack.

```
npm run start
```

But when I run my tests I get an error saying:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    stylex.create should never be called. It should be compiled away.
```

I'm using very basic configuration from the [stylx website](https://stylexjs.com/docs/learn/installation/).

This stylex is what is causing the error:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { SectionLayoutProps } from 'common/utils/types';
import { layoutStyle } from 'common/styles/layout.stylex';
import * as stylex from '@stylexjs/stylex';

export default function SectionLayout({ children, testId = null }: SectionLayoutProps) {
  return (
    <div
      data-testid={testId}
      {...stylex.props(layoutStyle.sectionLayout)}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

common/styles/layout.stylex.ts

```
import * as stylex from '@stylexjs/stylex';

export const layoutStyle = stylex.create({
  sectionLayout: {
    paddingTop: '20px',
    paddingBottom: '20px',
  },
});
```

I added the plugins to my babel and webpack config files:

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
...
plugins: [
    new StylexPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.[contenthash].css',
      // get webpack mode and set value for dev
      dev: true,
      test: true,
      // Use statically generated CSS files and not runtime injected CSS.
      // Even in development.
      runtimeInjection: false,
      // optional. default: 'x'
      // classNamePrefix: 'x',
      // Required for CSS variable support
      unstable_moduleResolution: {
        // type: 'commonJS' | 'haste'
        // default: 'commonJS'
        type: 'commonJS',
        // The absolute path to the root directory of your project
        rootDir: __dirname,
      },
    }),
]
```

babel.config.js

```
const styleXPlugin = require('@stylexjs/babel-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      styleXPlugin,
      {
        dev: true,
        // Set this to true for snapshot testing
        // default: false
        test: true,
        // Required for CSS variable support
        unstable_moduleResolution: {
          // type: 'commonJS' | 'haste'
          // default: 'commonJS'
          type: 'commonJS',
          // The absolute path to the root directory of your project
          rootDir: __dirname,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was jest was not set up to use babel, so the stylex was not compiling when I ran the tests. Solution:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-jest
```

and add this to the jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
...
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
    },
}
```

Works fine now.